# Using trigonometric identities to prove following series...

Tags: functions, trigonometry, fractions, products, trigonometric-series

I'm stuck on this problem:

If $(2^n + 1)\theta = \pi$,

then find the value of:

> $$2^n \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos(2^k\theta)$$

I have no idea how to start. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2^n \cos\theta \cos2\theta\cos2^2 \theta... \cos 2^{n-1} \theta =\frac{2^n\sin\theta \cos\theta \cos2\theta\cos2^2 \theta... \cos 2^{n-1} \theta}{\sin\theta}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin2^n\theta}{\sin\theta}=\frac{\sin(\pi-\theta)}{\sin\theta}=1.$$

Comment: How do we simply $\frac{\sin2^(n-1) \theta}{\sin\theta}$?

Comment: I used $\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$ $n$ times.

Comment: Well, the final answer given for this question is 1. How do we reach there from this result? @gimusi the infinite product looks promising for small angles since then $\sin\theta = \theta$ and then $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = 1$

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your given: $2^n+1=\pi$ seems very strange.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. The question was$(2^n + 1)\theta = \pi$

Comment: I also fixed. See now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71474/discussion-between-le-connoisseur-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use [Viète's infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Vi%C3%A8te's_infinite_product)

$$\cos\frac{\alpha}{2} \cdot \cos \frac{\alpha}{4}
\cdot \cos \frac{\alpha}{8} \cdots = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos \frac{\alpha}{2^n}
= \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha}$$

and plug in $\alpha=2^n \theta$